# Get site extension for slot resource id

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have a slot resource which has a subresources containing the app settings.
The app settings needs a dependsOn like this:

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites/siteextensions', concat(variables('webAppServiceName'), '/', variables('deploySlotName'), copyIndex(1)), 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites')]"
```

When using the above dependsOn, I am getting the error:

'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource type including resource provider namespace.

How do I specify the resourceId for this site extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resourceId` to specify the resource ID, like this:

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites/siteextensions', variables('extensionName'))]"
```

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)